# substitute file names using rename

Tags: shell, sed, rename

I want to rename files names by substituting all the characters starting from "_ " followed by eight capital letter and keep only the extension.

```
4585_10_148_H2A119Ub_GTCTGTCA_S51_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt.fm
4585_10_148_H3K27me3_TCTTCACA_S51_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt.fm
4585_27_128_Bap1_Bethyl_ACAGATTC_S61_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt.fw
4585_32_148_1_INPUT_previous_AGAGTCAA_S72_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt.bw
```

expected output

```
4585_10_148_H2A119Ub.fm
4585_10_148_H3K27me3.fm
4585_27_128_Bap1_Bethyl.fm
4585_32_148_1_INPUT_previous.fm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for f in *; do
    target=$(echo "${f}" | sed -E 's/_[[:upper:]]{8}.*\././')
    mv "${f}" "${target}"
done
```

The key thing is the `-E` argument to `sed`, since it enables expanded regular expressions.

Comment: Just noticed a copy/paste error from my terminal (forgot the `echo` for the `sed` command).  If you tried this and nothing happened, that's the reason why.

Comment: the files are renamed like this   4585_10_148_H2A119Ub_GTCTGTCA.fm instead of 4585_10_148_H2A119Ub.fm

Comment: this worked of me:         for f in $(ls); do
    target=$(echo "${f}" | sed -r 's/(_[[:upper:]]{8})[^.]*//')
    # Remove the echo after you've sanity checked the output
    echo mv "${f}" "${target}"
done

Comment: please don't suggest parsing ls, and here just replacing `$(ls)` with `*` will do - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for details.. also, `-E` is better choice for enabling ERE.. only some old versions use `sed -r` instead of `sed -E`

Comment: @beginner - Sorry, I misread your question and thought you wanted to change things *after* the eight caps; question has been updated.

Comment: @Sundeep - Thanks for the feedback (incorporated into the answer). Interestingly, I don't have `-E` in `man sed` on my system, but it works (tried with `busybox sed` as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rename` (a.k.a. `prename` or `Perl rename`) like this:

```
rename --dry-run 's|_[[:upper:]]{8}.*\.|.|' *
```

**Sample Output**

```
'4585_10_148_H2A119Ub_GTCTGTCA_S51_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt.fm' would be renamed to '4585_10_148_H2A119Ub.fm'
'4585_32_148_1_INPUT_previous_AGAGTCAA_S72_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt.bw' would be renamed to '4585_32_148_1_INPUT_previous.bw'
```

Remove the `--dry-run` and run again for real, if the output looks good.

This has several added benefits:

- that it will warn and avoid any conflicts if two files rename to the same thing,
- that it can rename across directories, creating any necessary intermediate directories on the way,
- that you can do a dry run first to test it,
- that you can use arbitrarily complex Perl code to specify the new name.

---

On a Mac, install it with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install rename
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
for i in *.fm; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/_GTCTGTCA_S51_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt//g'); done;
for i in *.fm; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/_TCTTCACA_S51_mcdf_mdup_ngsFlt//g'); done;
```

Comment: i would like to know if i can use any king of regular expression. I have n number of files with the same pattern .

Comment: this for loop will work for any number of `$i`'s(files)