# grouping folders with same name

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to group all the subdirectories with the same names to a new directory (create if not present)using awk

I appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: You said `I have a Directory with folder names like below`NOTE here word folder terminology is used in Windows o.s and directory is *NIX o.s ones. So what you are trying to convey here is confusing, could you please do edit your Question with more details and let us know then?

Comment: What are the preconditions? Are all those target folders have `L0..` suffix?

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice Linux user.  I am not good with the terminology. Yes, all the folder names have suffix L001,L002 and so on. I am trying to ignore everything after first "_" and create new directory like A1, B1.

Comment: But why do you want to use awk? Awk doesn't have a reliable builtin for moving files, creating directories etc.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at some examples on grouping files with awk on stack overflows. So I was trying some awk commands.  The solution need not be an awk command. @oguz ismail

Comment: Almost identical... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379836/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Almost, but I don't think that that question has a good answer

Comment: @oguzismail In what way, please? It has a very robust, succinct, accepted answer - by me.

Comment: @oguzismail Wow! Let's agree to differ. Your *"non-standard"* tool is my extremely powerful *"tried-and-tested"* tool that has been available for all Unixes/Linuxes and macOS since the year dot. The fact it is written in Perl which is maybe difficult to read does not deter me any more from using it than the fact that I don't understand the microcode in my car's Engine Management Unit deters me from driving my car. Anyone else's mileage may vary 

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's not standard

Comment: @oguzismail How is it "not standard"? [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Languages/LSB-Languages.html) requires Perl...

Comment: @BenjaminW. I was talking about POSIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a simple for loop like this:

```
for dir in ./*_*/; do
  echo mkdir -p "${dir%%_*}"   &&
  echo mv "$dir"* "${dir%%_*}" &&
  echo rm -r "$dir"
done
```

If its output looks good, remove `echo`es.