# Concatenate directory and file name in GNU parallel

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, gnu-parallel

I have the following directory structure:

```
dir1/file.ogg
dir2/file.ogg
dir3/file.ogg
     file2.ogg
```

I would like to convert all `.ogg` files to `.wav` with GNU Parallel. Here's where I got thus far:

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -print0 | parallel -0 ffmpeg -i {} outputdir/{/.}.wav
```

The problem here is that although obviously directories have different names, the files inside have the same name. The aforementioned command will continuously overwrite the content of the directory. What I'd like instead is:

```
outputdir/dir1_file.ogg
outputdir/dir2_file.ogg
outputdir/dir3_file.ogg
outputdir/dir3_file2.ogg
```

Essentially, I'd like to extract the subdirectory name and concatenate it with file basename and put my own extension.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could do a quick first pass with `rename` to get the files renamed and in the right directory then use **GNU Parallel** to do format conversion.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379836/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks, it was a valid option if taking a single pass with `parallel` would not be an option.

There were two votes claiming the question isn't about programming. @Philippe clearly demonstrated that there's a programming solution to it (in Perl). Perhaps next time I will make it more explicit that I seek SO-worthy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using perl transformation, this command should achieve the required effect :

```
find . -name '*.ogg' -type f -print0 | parallel -0 echo ffmpeg -i {} outputdir/{= '$_ =~ s[^\./][]; $_ =~ s[/][_]g; $_ =~ s[ogg$][wav]g;' =}
```

Remove `echo` to run ffmpeg command

Comment: Almost there. The only issue with the solution is that every file treated this way gets a prefix `._`, e.g. `._dir1_file.ogg`. As my perl is non-existent, I'd appreciate help in fixing this last bit.

Comment: Updated now, please check,