# create a folder for each file

Tags: bash, file, directory

I have different files that their names contain the same pattern - 'part + (number)'. For example:

```
part 1.txt
part 2.txt
```

I want to create a folder for each file, to name the folder in the same name as the file, and to insert the file into his matching folder.

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379836/2836621

Comment: Same name as in the directory will have the `.txt` extension as well?

Answer (score 0):

To move regular files with prefix `part` containing a suffix, you could do:

```
shop -s nullglob
for file in part*.*; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  dir=${file%.*}
  mkdir -p "$dir" && mv -i "$file" "$dir"
done
```

This enables Bash's shell options `nullglob` to expand non-matching patterns to a null string and the
test `[ -f "$file" ] || continue` skips non-regular files.
The pattern `${file%.*}` removes the suffix from the filename.
Option `-p` ignores an already existing directory and `-i` prompts if the file should already exist in the directory.

Comment: You're right, `nullglob` can be removed if the file check is present. This is redundant.