# Batch re-name files in multiple directories on MacOS

Tags: macos

I have around 500 JSON files sitting in their own directories that I need to re-name.

Every JSON file has the name, "list.json".

So what I need is a batch file operation for MacOS of some sort that will look in all the directories for files matching "list.json" and change the name to match name of the directory the file is sitting in. What kind of script do I need to do this?

Comment: AppleScript or bash.

Comment: With `rename`, example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58379836/2836621